# C# variable reference confusion

Tags: c#

Here is the example code:

```
List<List<Pet>> petsList = new List<List<Pet>>();

List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet>()
{
    new Pet {Name = "Whiskers"},
    new Pet {Name = "Boots"},
    new Pet {Name = "Bradley"},
};
petsList.Add(pets);

pets = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Name).ToList();

foreach (Pet pet in petsList[0])
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", pet.Name);
}
```

the complete code can be found here:https://pastebin.com/raw/uB2B7A9g

The ouput of this code is not what I would have expected.

I would have expected: 
Boots
Bradley
Whiskers

But the actual output is:
Whiskers
Boots
Bradley

isn't `pets` just a pointer?

so if I add `pets` to the `petsList`, and then modify `pets`, then `petsList[0]` should point to the modified variable?

But this is not the case, `petsList[0]` points to the unmodified `pets` variable.

the only way to fix this is to do:

```
List<List<Pet>> petsList = new List<List<Pet>>();

List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet>()
{
    new Pet {Name = "Whiskers"},
    new Pet {Name = "Boots"},
    new Pet {Name = "Bradley"},
};

pets = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Name).ToList();

petsList.Add(pets);

foreach (Pet pet in petsList[0])
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", pet.Name);
}
```

Comment: .Add() function doesn't add variable with the reference. I think if you 
shoudl try using petList[0] = pets and check

Comment: It would work as you expected if the Add method signature would be `Add(ref T)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> isn't pets just a pointer?

Yes, `pets` is reference type

> so if I add pets to the petsList, and then modify pets, then
>   petsList[0] should point to the modified variable?

Correct in case when you *"modify pets"*.
But line  `pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Name).ToList();` will not modify existed collection, instead it will return new instance of `List<Pet>`.

So in your sample `petsList[0]` will still reference to the original collection, where `pets` after ordering will reference to new collection.

For modifying existed collection you can use [List.Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/3da4abas(v=vs.110).aspx) method, but because you collection is collection of type `Pet` - you need create custom comparer for this type. Without custom comparer items will be sorted by reference.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is not with the equality of the references after `Add()`.
If you add this checking for the Reference Equality you will see where is the problem:

```
petsList.Add(pets);
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(petsList[0],pets)); // true
pets = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Name).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(petsList[0], pets)); // false
```

When you write `pets = pets.OrderBy(pet => pet.Name).ToList();` you are changing the reference to which the `pets` was bound and after that `petsList[0`] and `pets` are not equal by reference any more. So you will need to set `petsList[0]` to that new reference also.